# I Already downloaded dart version 2.14.0

Tags: dart

app name] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in app name...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.3.

Because app name depends on link_preview_generator >=1.2.0 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because app name depends on link_preview_generator >=1.2.0 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

but i just downloaded the version 2.14.0, and is there in my cmd when i check my dart verison is 2.14.0 but in my vscode it shows me  2.12.3.

Comment: Add it to path environment variable.

Comment: Please show us your pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

in `pubspec.yaml` make sure  sdk is greater or equal to  2.14

example :

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: i already make it like that but it keep showing same error to me